# Get all sessions from selenium server

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using remote driver (chrome) with java. For version 2.53 I was getting the sessions by:

```
httpCommandExecutor.execute (new Command (sessionId, "getAllSessions"));
```

for new versions (3.141), it seems it is not working. I am getting:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: No command or response codec has been defined. Unable to proceed
```

Any idea?

Comment: What exactly do you do with the `sessions`?

Comment: Sometimes session with the same user-data-dir hangs on the server. So I want to kill the previous ones first. Honestly, I don't know the current status but in my version, we could not run a second session with the same user-data-dir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I solved this with the same method:

```
httpCommandExecutor.execute (new Command (sessionId, "getAllSessions"));
```

But the difference is I am running this after I create the new session. So I am checking the session ids to not kill the newly created session:

```
Response response = httpCommandExecutor.execute (new Command (newSessionId, "getAllSessions"));

// Don't kill the new session
for (HashMap<String, Object> sessionParams : (ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>) response.getValue ()) {
    SessionId sessionId = new SessionId ((String) sessionParams.get("id"))
    if (!newSessionId.equals(sessionId)){
        httpCommandExecutor.execute (new Command (sessionId, "quit"));
    }
}
```